# Set min value of each row of a tensor to zero without using explicit loops

Tags: python, pytorch

Here's the problem.

> Return a copy of x, where the minimum value along each row has been
> set to 0.
>
> For example, if x is:
>
> ```
> x = torch.tensor([[
>         [10, 20, 30],
>         [ 2,  5,  1]
>       ]])
> ```
>
> Then y = zero_row_min(x) should be:
>
> ```
> torch.tensor([
>     [0, 20, 30],
>     [2,  5,  0]
>   ])
> ```
>
> Your implementation should use reduction and indexing operations;
> you should   not use any explicit loops. The input tensor should not
> be modified.
>
> Inputs:
>
> - x: Tensor of shape (M, N)
>
> Returns:
>
> - y: Tensor of shape (M, N) that is a copy of x, except the minimum value
>   along each row is replaced with 0.

It has been hinted at that [clone](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.clone.html#torch.clone) and [argmin](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.argmin.html#torch.argmin) should be used.

I'm having trouble understanding how to do this without a loop and my current code below (although it gets the problem right) is crude. I'm looking for a better way to solve this problem.

```
  x0 = torch.tensor([[10, 20, 30], [2, 5, 1]])
  x1 = torch.tensor([[2, 5, 10, -1], [1, 3, 2, 4], [5, 6, 2, 10]])

  func(x0)
  func(x1)
  
  def func(x):

    y = None

    # g = x.argmin(dim=1)

    g = x.min(dim=1)[1]

    if x.shape[0] == 2:
      x[0,:][g[0]] = 0
      x[1,:][g[1]] = 0
    elif x.shape[0] == 3:
      x[0,:][g[0]] = 0
      x[1,:][g[1]] = 0
      x[2,:][g[2]] = 0

    y = x
  
    return y
```

Comment: The idea should be `copy_of_array[argmin_indices] = 0`.

Comment: Can you provide expected shape for each of your variables? e.g. `(1000, 2, 12)` or whatever.

Comment: @Reinderien Sure, `x0 = torch.tensor([[10, 20, 30], [2, 5, 1]])` and `x1 = torch.tensor([[2, 5, 10, -1], [1, 3, 2, 4], [5, 6, 2, 10]])`. I've added them to the original post for clarification as well.

Comment: @Andrew I believe that's similar to the way I went about solving it. It works, but I have to manually iterate over each row to mutate the min() value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not much of a code review, but this should work:

```
def zero_min(x):
    y = x.clone()
    y[torch.arange(x.shape[0]), torch.argmin(x, dim=1)] = 0
    return y
```

In each row, if the minimum is not unique, then only the occurrence with the smallest index will be zeroed out.

To zero out all the occurrences, you could do something like the following:

```
def zero_em_all_min(x):
    y = x.clone()
    y[x == x.min(dim=1, keepdims=True).values] = 0
    return y
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't think to use `torch.arange` to iterate through the rows. I'll ask on regular SE in the future.

Comment: @Ryan I'm happy it could be answered, but perhaps that is indeed the better platform for a similar question!